# Unable to update mysql table using PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I have two pages in php,

- php_mysql_multiple_edit2.php //the form
- php_mysql_multiple_edit.php //the script containing mysql update command

The script ran perfectly fine and updated the table when there were few entries in the database during testing, but does not update when I added the actual table.

I am getting the following error

> Notice: Undefined index: hdnLine in /var/www/ELP/php_mysql_multiple_edit.php on line 6 Notice: Undefined index: hdnLine in /var/www/ELP/php_mysql_multiple_edit.php on line 25 Save completed.

The code for the two are are:

**php_mysql_multiple_edit2.php**

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Employee Leave Portal</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p style="text-align: center">
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </p>

<?
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("test");
$i=(int)0;
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM leave_db ORDER BY firstname ASC";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL."]");
?>
<form name="frmMain" method="post" action="php_mysql_multiple_edit.php">
<table align="center" width="600" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="91"> <div align="center">Employee_id </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="98"> <div align="center">firstname </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="198"> <div align="center">lastname </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">C1 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">C2 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">C3 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">Ct </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">P1 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">P2 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">P3 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">Pt </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">M1 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">M2 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">M3 </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">Mt </div></th>
    <th bgcolor="#3366CC" width="50"> <div align="center">Tt </div></th>
  </tr>
<?
$i =0;
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $i = $i + 1;
?>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center">
    <input type="hidden" name="employee_id<?=$i;?>" size="5" value="<?=$objResult["employee_id"];?>">
    <input type="text" name="employee_id<?=$i;?>" size="5" value="<?=$objResult["employee_id"];?>">
    </div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><input type="text" name="firstname<?=$i;?>" size="10" value="<?=$objResult["firstname"];?> "></td>
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><input type="text" name="lastname<?=$i;?>" size="10" value="<?=$objResult["lastname"];?> "></td>
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="C1<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["C1"];?>"></div></td>  
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="C2<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["C2"];?>"></div></td>  
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="C3<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["C3"];?>"></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#B2C2F0" width="50"> <div align="center"><?=$objResult["Ct"];?></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="P1<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["P1"];?>"></div></td>  
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="P2<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["P2"];?>"></div></td>  
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="P3<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["P3"];?>"></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#B2C2F0" width="50"> <div align="center"><?=$objResult["Pt"];?></div></td>     
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="M1<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["M1"];?>"></div></td>  
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="M2<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["M2"];?>"></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#3366CC"><div align="center"><input type="number" name="M3<?=$i;?>" size="2" value="<?=$objResult["M3"];?>"></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#B2C2F0" width="50"> <div align="center"><?=$objResult["Mt"];?></div></td>
    <td bgcolor="#00FFFF" width="50"> <div align="center"><?=$objResult["Tt"];?></div></td>
  </tr>
<?
}
?>

</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<input type="hidden" name="hdnLine" value="<?=(int)$i;?>">
</form>
<?
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**php_mysql_multiple_edit.php**

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or die(mysql_error());
$objDB = mysql_select_db("test");
$i = (int)0;
//*** Update Condition ***//
    for($i=1;$i<=$_POST["hdnLine"];$i++)
    {
        $strSQL = "UPDATE leave_db SET ";
        $strSQL .="employee_id = '".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",firstname = '".$_POST["firstname$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",lastname = '".$_POST["lastname$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",C1 = '".$_POST["C1$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",C2 = '".$_POST["C2$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",C3 = '".$_POST["C3$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",P1 = '".$_POST["P1$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",P2 = '".$_POST["P2$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",P3 = '".$_POST["P3$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",M1 = '".$_POST["M1$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",M2 = '".$_POST["M2$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .=",M3 = '".$_POST["M3$i"]."' ";
        $strSQL .="WHERE employee_id = '".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."' ";
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
    }

    for($i=1;$i<=$_POST["hdnLine"];$i++)
    {
        $SUMC1="select (C1+C2-C3) as 'SUMC2' from leave_db where employee_id='".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."'";
        $queryC1=mysql_query($SUMC1);
        $rowC1=mysql_fetch_array($queryC1);
        $final_sumC=$rowC1['SUMC2'];
        $update_queryC=" update leave_db set Ct=$final_sumC where employee_id='".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."'";
        $objQueryC = mysql_query($update_queryC);

        $SUMP1="select (P1+P2-P3) as 'SUMP2' from leave_db where employee_id='".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."'";
        $queryP1=mysql_query($SUMP1);
        $rowP1=mysql_fetch_array($queryP1);
        $final_sumP=$rowP1['SUMP2'];
        $update_queryP=" update leave_db set Pt=$final_sumP where employee_id='".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."'";
        $objQueryP = mysql_query($update_queryP);

        $SUMM1="select (M1+M2-M3) as 'SUMM2' from leave_db where employee_id='".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."'";
        $queryM1=mysql_query($SUMM1);
        $rowM1=mysql_fetch_array($queryM1);
        $final_sumM=$rowM1['SUMM2'];
        $update_queryM=" update leave_db set Mt=$final_sumM where employee_id='".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."'";
        $objQueryM = mysql_query($update_queryM);

        $SUMT1="select (Ct+Pt+Mt) as 'SUMT2' from leave_db where employee_id='".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."'";
        $queryT1=mysql_query($SUMT1);
        $rowT1=mysql_fetch_array($queryT1);
        $final_sumT=$rowT1['SUMT2'];
        $update_queryT=" update leave_db set Tt=$final_sumT where employee_id='".$_POST["employee_id$i"]."'";
        $objQueryT = mysql_query($update_queryT);

    }

    //header("location:$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]");
    //exit();

$strSQL2 = "SELECT * FROM leave_db ORDER BY firstname ASC";
$objQuery2 = mysql_query($strSQL2) or die ("Error Query [".$strSQL2."]");
echo "Save completed.  Click <a href='php_mysql_multiple_edit2.php'>here</a> to view.";
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>`
```

Comment: *PSA:* The `mysql_*` functions are [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will prevent you from upgrading in the future. Instead, use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: I see this type of question all the time, you should read [common database debugging for PHP and MySQL](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2013/04/common-debugging-php-mysql/).

Comment: Please, before you write **any** more SQL interfacing code, you must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). Also, `mysql_query` should not be used in new applications. It's a deprecated interface that's being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and will make your database code easier to get right.

Comment: Your script is susceptible to SQL injection. You may want to at least call `mysql_escape` on the `$_POST` values.

Comment: What does php_mysql_multiple_edit2.php have as the value for the `hdnLine` input? What does var_dump($_POST) show in php_mysql_multiple_edit.php?

Comment: did you get noticed that you are no using `<?php` all the time?

Comment: Thanks Jason and tadman for the advice. Will definitely update the code using PDO. Thanks aefxx, your advice helped me to get the code work. POST was unable to send enough data to the next page, so I changed setting in php.ini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the comments people, aefxx's advice helped me the most.
I had to change settings in php.ini to make it run for the time being as I will migrate to PDO soon.

Changes made in php.ini:

1. increased post_max_size to 20M
2. increased max_execution_time to -1
3. increased max_input_vars to 2000